# Does a model with 0.5 AUROC imply an average precision equal to the proportion of positive examples?

Tags: machine-learning, roc, precision-recall, average-precision

A random model has an area under the ROC curve equal to 0.5.

We also know that a random model has an area under the Precision-Recall curve equal to the proportion (*p*) of positive examples.

Then, here's my question. Does a model with an AUCROC of 0.5 always imply an AUCPR of *p*? Or is it possible to be different? If so, how can this scenario happen?